# Adding a single field adds a lot of seconds to page generation time

Tags: laravel-backpack

I know in this case I must then customize storing/updating data. No problem in this side.

I m adding this field

```
    $this->crud->addField([
        'label' => 'Denominazione',
        'type' => 'text',
        'tab' => 'Cliente/Richiedente',
        'name' => 'customer.name',
        'wrapper' => ['class' => 'form-group col-md-6'],
        'attributes' => [
            'class' => 'form-control text-uppercase'
        ]
    ]);
```

The entity being edited is a Practice

Practice has a 1:1 relationship to Customer

```
public function customer()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Customer::class, 'practice_id');
}
```

and customer has the field named `name`

What I'm diong **works perfectly** but the problem is that adding this field, bring page load time from <3 sec to >9 second

I've only 1 record in practices table and only 1 record in customers table

customer.practice_id point to practice.id and is a foreign key in the db

I think i'm doing something wrong here, and I don't know why it's adding so much time to load a single field !

### Notes

> I am using debug bar for laravel, so I've execution time of ALL queries. The problem is NOT a slow query.
>
> adding field to a different tab doesn't change; removing tabs at all doesn't change execution time; removing this specific field removes 8 seconds of 9 total execution. Why ?!
>
> I'm using latest version of backpack, 5.3.5, with also a paid Pro package
>
> Also note I'm not using a TONS of views
>
> With the field
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> Without  the field
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an issue on backpack crud to full document my timings. I found 'where' the issue is in the backpack code, but NOT WHY. And also, I've no idea on how to make it reproducible

The problem is when internally backpack try to 'guess' the default field name of a relationship.

By my knowledge, the implementation is not optimized, but has no problem, but a specific call causes 7 seconds of 'hang'

That said, I found 2 workarounds

1. Adding a `attribute` field to each field coming from a relationship
2. (instead of 1.) Adding *in each models* a `public function identifiableAttribute()` returning the default field name for a model, just to avoid at all the calling of that code

So

1. I'am not sure if it's not a strange bug of framework, backpack or php, but 2 of my coworkers, with same code, has same problem, but, we cannot reproduce in no other project, so it's of course due to a moltitude of factors we cannot understand
2. Is there 2 workarounds and now our code bring a full monster page on < 1 second

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to reproduce that specific issue.

I've create a CRUD, added 2 Fields (one text and other hasOne.relation_attribute), with or without the `hasOne` field the load times are similar. 200ms/350ms

From the issue you described I would expect atleast for it to go to 1 second or something similar when I added the hasOne relation

[image: without the field]

[image: with the field]

The times are very similar, if I refresh the page some more times I get less loading time with the hasOne field that with only the text field.

If you use the `hasOne` relation in any other crud you can notice the same behavior? Or is it only in this specific CRUD?

I tried it also in our demo, specifically the MonsterCrud that has ALOT of fields and it's not optimized. Removing the hasOne fields from there has not the impact you are describing here.

If you change the field place instead of deleting, same happens ?

Cheers

Comment: Yes, changing position doesn't change the result. I added my own answer to accept that is a strange case, but not definitively a bug of laravel and/or backpack. 

Also: what is monster crud?

Comment: Our project IS a monster crud. The update is a form with 8 tabs, with over 100 fields, including 3 repeatables :) Anyway, a single call to a single addField is causing the problem in my question. No known explanation.. sorry